# package installation using virtualenv

Tags: python, virtualenv

I would like to install some python dependencies using virtualenv:    http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

While running this code:

```
pip install decorator
```

I receive this error:

```
bash: /home/pol/Softwares/python/venv/bin/pip: 
/home/pol/Softwares/python/venv/bin/python2: bad interpreter:
Too many levels of symbolic links
```

How can the error solved please and where is the root of the conflict in your view? Thanks

Comment: Show haw You create a virtualenv

Comment: I followed the instructions given here : http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/. Thanks

Comment: 1. http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: Probably venv is failed. Remove `venv` directory and create it one more time.